# how to scanf a number-and-operator series using a while loop?

Tags: c, loops, scanf, rpn, postfix-notation

I have a stdin input like " 33 44 55 + 66 * + = ", (i.e, Reverse Polish notation，RPN), and I use codes as follows to parse it. But scanf("%d") reads '+' and discards it, how to ungetc the operator and make it be read by scanf(" %c ")? What is the best way to solve the problem. Thanks.

```
while ((reta = scanf("%d", &operand)) == 1 || (retb = scanf(" %c ", &operator)) == 1) {
  if (reta == 1) push(exprStack, operand);
  else if (retb == 1) {
    operand = pop(exprStack);
    /* function pmtd executes some basic calculation, i.e., plus, minus, times and divide */
    push(exprStack, pmtd(operator, pop(exprStack), operand));
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out `strtok(3)`.

Comment: Must you use `scanf()`? It's usually not appropriate for interactive input. Use `fgets()` and parse the input string yourself.

Comment: @Carl: strtok may not very OK, delimers will be discarded by strtok(3).

Comment: @Greg I am trying to work with scanf properly, and I don't want to be confused by scanf. I'll try fgets sometime.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to use a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  It'll take a bit of learning if you haven't used it before, but there are examples and tutorials for arithmetic calculations like what you want to do, and ANTLR generates C code that will do a proper, correct job of parsing according to the grammar you define (unlike hand-written parsing code, which usually has quirks if not outright bugs).

If you use ANTLR, it can parse the input into an "abstract syntax tree," or AST.  If you define your grammar carefully, this AST can be traversed with a straightforward recursion to do the computations, one by one, making this kind of evaluator quite simple and robust.

Answer (score 0):

Can't ungetc by scanf. use sscanf by same point again, or scanf("%s") -> check string and convert.

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int reta=0,retb=0;
    int operand;
    char operator;
    char token[16];

    token[15] = '\0';
    while (0 != scanf(" %15s", token)) {
        if(1 == (reta = sscanf(token, "%d", &operand)))
            printf("operand : %d\n", operand);
        else if(1 == (retb = sscanf(token, "%c", &operator))){
            printf("operator : %c\n", operator);
            if(operator == '=') break;
        } else
            printf("else\n");
        reta=retb=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strong suggestion:

1. Get the string with fgets().  There are many, many good reasons for doing so.
2. Once you've GOT the string, try parsing it with sscanf() if you wish.

   "sscanf()" is the SAME as "scanf" - except that it works with in-memory strings (instead of directly reading stdin).
3. Or use strtok() if you prefer.  Or write your own functions to parse and interpret the string.
4. I suspect you'll find sscanf() is too limited for your purposes.  But if you want to try it - if only out of curiousity - cool.  Just do yourself a favor and use "fgets()" to get the input from stdin first.

IMHO .. PSM

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using Bison (a parser generator).
There's a perfect example of a RPN calculator in the manual. This example is used all over the manual.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/RPN-Calc.html#RPN-Calc

I recommend you reading it from there, which will be better than any answer you could get from here.